# How to add a class and then remove that same class in the vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, hamburger-menu

I have the following div:

```
<div class="col bg-color-red-4">
            <a href="#"  v-on:click="showMobileMenu = !showMobileMenu">
                <i class="hamburger hamburger--3dx " v-bind:class="{ 'is-active': showMobileMenu }" >
                    <span class="hamburger-box">
                        <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
                    </span>
                </i>
            </a>
            <p>3DX</p>
        </div>

 data(){
        return {
            showMobileMenu: false
        }
    },
```

That is visually like this:

[image]

basically it's a button that allows me to open the left panel:
[image]

When you click on the button you add the class 'is-active' that allows the change of form, leaving it like this:

[image]

and it effectively opens the left panel, but after turning off the left panel, that is, returning to the view that I was in, this one finds the class added.

then I need that when I click, I change the shape to an "X", when I open the left panel, but when I come back I do not have the form "X", that is, it does not contain the class 'is-active' anymore

Beforehand thank you very much.

Comment: What is that "X"? Show the template for it.

Comment: "X", is the effect that the hamburger icon has

Comment: Where does it come from? Is it a pre-built component (from others) you are using? Is it a component you are creating yourself? Is it just HTML in your same template?

Answer (score 1):

**At first** read the official docs:
[https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#ad][1]

**At second** - check Matt Oestreich's answer

**At third** - you can also bind classes to the variables like this:

```
<div
  class="static"
  v-bind:class="{ active: isActive, 'text-danger': hasError }"
/>
```

And in a **Vue.js** script:

```
 data: {
  isActive: true,
  hasError: false
}
```

Comment: Good answer, Artyom!

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to the `class` attribute and supply specific classes that way..

---

[[CodePen Mirror]](https://codepen.io/oze4/pen/mYLdLN)

---

***Code Snippet:***

```js
const vm = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    status: false,
    bars: "fa fa-bars",
    times: "fa fa-times",
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuetify/1.5.14/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/font-awesome@4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.6/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
      <v-container>
        <i 
          style="cursor:pointer;"
          :class="status ? times : bars" 
          @click="status = !status"
          ></i>
        <h1>Click The Icon</h1>
        <h3>It is currently {{ status ? 'open' : 'closed' }}</h3>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

---